# powershell catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodException] error

Tags: powershell, throw, catch-block

in powershell, under certain condition , i do this :

```
throw [System.Management.Automation.MethodException]
```

later i have catch like this :

```
catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodException]
{

catch
{
```

My code falls into the second (general) catch. 
when i look at  $_.Exception in the second catch, it says 'System.Management.Automation.MethodException' - so why come Powershell does not catch it in the first catch ?
 How can i fix this?

Thanks, Peter

Comment: `throw [System.Management.Automation.MethodException]` -> `throw [System.Management.Automation.MethodException]::new()`

Answer (score 1):

PetSerAl has it right in the comment; you need to create an *instance* of the `MethodException` class.

His suggestion is nice and terse:

```
throw [System.Management.Automation.MethodException]::new()
```

But it only works on PowerShell 5+. In earlier versions:

```
$ex = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.MethodException
throw $ex
```

Or, an easy way to use this in any version while including a message is to cast a `[String]` as the exception:

```
throw [System.Management.Automation.MethodException]"You messed up."
```